# How to create objects with array-properties in Python

Tags: python, list, object, self

I am looking for a way to implement an object as an array with different attributes in Python.
My idea is an object-index looking like this:

```
self[row][col].item1 = True
self[row][col2].item2="xkcd"
...
```

I'm pretty sure I saw this before, however I can't recreate a class which allows this. My best call so far is (in dummy-code):

```
def __init__(self, posxy=[[...]*10]):
    self.posxy=posxy
```

which at least allows me to give the attribute posxy all informations I want. However I would strongly prefer the first variant. Could someone with more experience in object-oriented programming please help me out?

Answer (score 2):

You want to look at the [Emulating container types](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-container-types) section of the Python datamodel.

At the very least, you'll have to implement the [`__getitem__` hook](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__) to let your class handle `[...]` indexing. This will only be pass the *first* `row` value, whatever this method returns will be indexed for `[col]`.

You can choose to handle tuples instead, indexing on `self[row, col]` too, the `key` argument will then be passed a tuple of two values instead:

```
def __getitem__(self, key):
    row, col = key  # unpack the tuple
    return self.matrix[row][col]
```

Answer (score 1):

To use the `[]` notation you need to override the [`__getitem__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__) special method. A simple example:

```
class X:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.data[index]
```

So to have rows and columns you can try the following:

```
class Row:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.data[index]

class Matrix:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = [Row(d) for d in data]

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.data[index]
```

Simple demo:

```
class X:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.item1 = value

x = Matrix([[X('11'), X('12'), X('13')], [X('21'), X('22'), X('23')]])

print x[1][1].item1
```

Gives:

```
>>>22
```

Answer (score 1):

You can inherit from defaultdict to get something like this:

```
import collections

class MyClass(collections.defaultdict):
  def __init__(self):
    collections.defaultdict.__init__(self, dict)
    self[0][0] = True
    self[0][1] ="xkcd"
```

ie, each top-level index yields a `dict`. If you want something more structured, your defaultdict needs a different factory function ... maybe it yields a MyInnerClass which is also a defaultdict, containing your eventual type.

All defaultdict is doing for you is implementing `__getitem__`, `__setitem__`, `__contains__` etc. See Martijn's link for the full list of methods, if you want to implement it by hand.